# AWS Aurora RDS Parameter Group - Is it possible to export from one account and import to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, group

I was hoping that there might be an easy way to export a parameter group from one account to another account.  This doesn't seem possible via the aws console.

I checked the aws cli rds command documentation, and there is the DESCRIBE command, which i have used to create a text or json output file.  But i am not seeing a way to import that pg.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have to do the same transition for **PostgreSQL** database, and here I have done the following :

**1.** Export Parameters from the Source Database Parameter Group:

```
aws rds describe-db-parameters --db-parameter-group-name <My-Parameter-Group-Name> >> My-Parameters.json
```

**2.** Edited **My-Parameters.json** by replacing the first key i.e. **Parameters** with **DBParameterGroupName**

Example portion of Parameters JSON **after EDIT**:

```
{
    "DBParameterGroupName": [
        {
            "ParameterName": "application_name",
            "Description": "Sets the application name to be reported in statistics and logs.",
            "Source": "engine-default",
            "ApplyType": "dynamic",
            "DataType": "string",
            "IsModifiable": true,
            "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot"
        },
......
```

**3.**
Created the new parameter group in the destination:

```
aws rds create-db-parameter-group \
    --db-parameter-group-name "<My-New-Parameter-Group-Name>" \
    --db-parameter-group-family "postgres13" \
    --description "<My-Parameter-Group-Description>" \
    --cli-input-json file://My-Parameters.json \
    --region <Preferred-Region>
```

Comment: this worked! so weird... thank you!

Comment: Yes I know its wired, and wondered why AWS does not give us direct instruction to do this simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ah...I should have looked a little deeper at the aws cli commands, before posting this question.  Sorry!

After posting, I just noticed that the create command accepts a json input file!
That will do what i need.

```
aws rds create-db-parameter-group \
    --db-parameter-group-name <group-name> \
    --db-parameter-group-family <group-family> \
    --description <group-description> \
    --cli-input-json file://<path-to-file>
```

Comment: Good find. I have wanted to do something like this, didn't find a way in the console, and assumed that doing it with the CLI would be more complicated. E.g. "detect which parameters were changed from their defaults and make some set of modify parameter groups commands out of that". BTW, with Aurora it's more common to use create-db-cluster-parameter-group.

Answer (score 0):

Great that you found a solution, also, you could evaluate use AWS Cloudformation Templates to deploy your configurations for multiples accounts in more easy way. Below you can find more information for AWS RDS Parameters Groups using AWS Cloudformation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbparametergroup.html

Also here is a blog for best practices to deploy AWS Resources using AWS Cloudformation.

[Best practices to deploy Amazon Aurora databases with AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-to-deploy-amazon-aurora-databases-with-aws-cloudformation/)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I wish the answer above would work, but I exported the parameters from account 1, then did the create and it gave me `Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "Parameters", must be one of: DBParameterGroupName, DBParameterGroupFamily, Description, Tags` because the JSON doesn't have the stuff you put at the command line.

Seems very dumb of AWS to provide an export tool that then won't re-import.